# Unity: ONLY rotate around an objects y axis, but the object in question already has changed rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine, axis, quaternions, euler-angles

like the title says, i essentially want to set the y rotation of gameobject1 to gameobject2, but gameobject1 already has changed rotation to something else than 0,0,0 in degrees. Say for example the rotation is 34, 50, 16. Since the rotation has changed the axis have changed too, meaning they aren't pointing in the x, y and z directions anymore. so if we try to get the y rot, we instead end up getting the rotation of an axis on the right, because of the rotation the y axis has moved there.

Sorry if im really vague with this, cannot explain this any better as its pretty late and i've tried to solve this for three days straight. Therefore, any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use transform.RotateAround(target, Vector3.up, float yourRotation), where for your problem target = Vector3.zero. See the doc here : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html

Comment: I got pretty close with this approach, however stil got some rare cases where suddenly the rotation would flip.

Comment: flip ? around another axis ?

Comment: yeah, it probably was me screwing things up though. Anyways i've solved this myself with a different approach, thanks for your time!